# Unable to read XML due to parent node

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML file

```
<eConnect xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <SOPTransactionType>
    <eConnectProcessInfo>
      <ConnectionString>Data Source=DGLSQL1;Initial Catalog=dgl;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI</ConnectionString>
      <EConnectProcsRunFirst>True</EConnectProcsRunFirst>
    </eConnectProcessInfo>
    <taSopLotAuto_Items>
      <taSopLotAuto>
        <SOPTYPE>2</SOPTYPE>
        <SOPNUMBE>435462</SOPNUMBE>
        <LNITMSEQ>16384</LNITMSEQ>
        <ITEMNMBR>7740</ITEMNMBR>
        <LOCNCODE>18</LOCNCODE>
        <QUANTITY>65</QUANTITY>
        <LOTNUMBR>15483D0104X68X</LOTNUMBR>
      </taSopLotAuto>
    </taSopLotAuto_Items>
  </SOPTransactionType>
</eConnect>
```

I am using the following code to read this file

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\SOP.XML");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/taSopLotAuto_Items/taSopLotAutoka");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{      
    string text = node["SOPTYPE"].InnerText; 
    Console.WriteLine(text + "\n");
}
```

Here I want to read the content of `<taSopLoAuto>`. But I am unable to read the file content. Is this because of top few lines written in document? Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: `taSopLotAuto_Items` is not the top-level item in your XML and `taSopLotAutoka` does not even exist. Rewrite your XPath.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279306/read-from-xml-files-with-or-without-a-namespace-using-xmldocument

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is an issue.  You can use Linq like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<eConnect xmlns:dt=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes\">" +
                  "<SOPTransactionType>" +
                    "<eConnectProcessInfo>" +
                      "<ConnectionString>Data Source=DGLSQL1;Initial Catalog=dgl;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI</ConnectionString>" +
                      "<EConnectProcsRunFirst>True</EConnectProcsRunFirst>" +
                    "</eConnectProcessInfo>" +
                    "<taSopLotAuto_Items>" +
                      "<taSopLotAuto>" +
                        "<SOPTYPE>2</SOPTYPE>" +
                        "<SOPNUMBE>435462</SOPNUMBE>" +
                        "<LNITMSEQ>16384</LNITMSEQ>" +
                        "<ITEMNMBR>7740</ITEMNMBR>" +
                        "<LOCNCODE>18</LOCNCODE>" +
                        "<QUANTITY>65</QUANTITY>" +
                        "<LOTNUMBR>15483D0104X68X</LOTNUMBR>" +
                      "</taSopLotAuto>" +
                      "<taSopLotAuto>" +
                        "<SOPTYPE>2</SOPTYPE>" +
                        "<SOPNUMBE>435462</SOPNUMBE>" +
                        "<LNITMSEQ>16384</LNITMSEQ>" +
                        "<ITEMNMBR>7740</ITEMNMBR>" +
                        "<LOCNCODE>18</LOCNCODE>" +
                        "<QUANTITY>65</QUANTITY>" +
                        "<LOTNUMBR>15483D0104X68X</LOTNUMBR>" +
                      "</taSopLotAuto>" +
                      "<taSopLotAuto>" +
                        "<SOPTYPE>2</SOPTYPE>" +
                        "<SOPNUMBE>435462</SOPNUMBE>" +
                        "<LNITMSEQ>16384</LNITMSEQ>" +
                        "<ITEMNMBR>7740</ITEMNMBR>" +
                        "<LOCNCODE>18</LOCNCODE>" +
                        "<QUANTITY>65</QUANTITY>" +
                        "<LOTNUMBR>15483D0104X68X</LOTNUMBR>" +
                      "</taSopLotAuto>" +
                    "</taSopLotAuto_Items>" +
                  "</SOPTransactionType>" +
                "</eConnect>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            List<XElement> taSopLotAutos = doc.Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "taSopLotAuto")
                .ToList();

            var results = taSopLotAutos.Select(x => new
            {
                sopType = (int)x.Element("SOPTYPE"),
                sopNumbe = (int)x.Element("SOPNUMBE"),
                lnitmsseg = (int)x.Element("LNITMSEQ"),
                locncode = (int)x.Element("LOCNCODE"),
                quantity = (int)x.Element("QUANTITY"),
                lotnumbr = (string)x.Element("LOTNUMBR")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I have multiple records under same root name how can I iterate them using a loop.

Comment: Which tag repeats for multiple records?  I don't know what you mean by a record.

Comment: Their is only one tage **<taSopLotAuto>** and its child occurs ones in file. If this tag repeats than how can I it.