# Get values from XML Document

Tags: c#, linq

So lets say I have this XML document:

```
<s:Envelope 
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
        xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <s:Header>
            <VsDebuggerCausalityData 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo4tYpt6X40FEk+VSAe5mc8MAAAAAP497cBuXfk+uFIOY80O0iuLtIW56q7hLktgVYPhbnHMACQAA
            </VsDebuggerCausalityData>
            <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" 
                xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-10490fb0-8ee0-4a4c-a8db-77242c9a3b7f-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">MIIF+TCCBOGgAwIBAgIQIWv3OdE866kXP/....t</o:BinarySecurityToken>
                <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" 
                    xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" 
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
                    </e:EncryptionMethod>
                    <KeyInfo 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">j0ZKFBmTz3Kj0cQ82rq63MYAR+0=</o:KeyIdentifier>
                        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <e:CipherData>
                        <e:CipherValue>ANCElFZ5v....==</e:CipherValue>
                    </e:CipherData>
                    <e:ReferenceList>
                        <e:DataReference URI="#_2" />
                    </e:ReferenceList>
                </e:EncryptedKey>
                <Signature 
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <SignedInfo>
                        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                        <Reference URI="#_1">
                            <Transforms>
                                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </Transforms>
                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                            <DigestValue>akiomlPdi6j1h6r9NDqmh9G1GD0=</DigestValue>
                        </Reference>
                    </SignedInfo>
                    <SignatureValue>LIjqWD/BXsoA0XNR7hv...==</SignatureValue>
                    <KeyInfo>
                        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-10490fb0-8ee0-4a4c-a8db-77242c9a3b7f-2" />
                        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </KeyInfo>
                </Signature>
            </o:Security>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body u:Id="_1">
            <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" 
                xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
                <e:CipherData>
                    <e:CipherValue>3kESnJnhc8K.....</e:CipherValue>
                </e:CipherData>
            </e:EncryptedData>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

I want to pragmatically get two values

1)  Header > Security > EncryptedKey > CipherData > CipherValue. So it would be ANCElFZ5v....==

2)  Body > EncryptedData > CipherData > CipherValue. So it would be 3kESnJnhc8K.....

I have been trying XML to LINQ but can't seem to figure it out.

I have been trying various thing like.  But it seems to be not working. Meaning I don't get any values.

```
XDocument file = XDocument.Load(stream);
var keyEnc = file.Root.Elements("Header").Elements("Security").Elements("EncryptedKey").Elements("CipherData").Elements("CipherValue").ToList();
```

Comment: You have to include the namespaces for that to work.  That or do queries on the `LocalName`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340411/use-linq-to-xml-with-xml-namespaces

Comment: How do you include the namespace?

Comment: Maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279306/read-from-xml-files-with-or-without-a-namespace-using-xmldocument ,  and in my experience `XElement` and `XPath` is also good way to read xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace was the issue.
var doc= XDocument.Load(stream);
XNamespace ns_e = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#";

var encrypKeys = doc.Root.Descendants(ns_e + "CipherValue").ToList();